# Sed command to replace date string 'DD-03-YYYY' with the string for the month, e.g. 'March'

Tags: regex, string, bash, date, sed

I have a data set with a long list of dates in the format 'DD-MM-YYYY'. The only important part to me is the month, and I would like to reformat these strings to have the string representation of the month, e.g replace '23-01-1994' with 'January'.

Is there a streamlined why in sed or some other utility to replace these strings with their month-name equivalents?

Comment: If you're okay with using awk, this question has some good answers: http://stackoverflow.com/q/14342108/477563

Comment: Is this about a special file with only one date in each line and nothing else, or are the dates embedded in text? Are multiple dates per line possible?

Comment: It is a csv like so: `12-04-1990, 234\n 11-03-2000, 1256\n`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you're okay with awk instead of sed, this works well:

```
awk -F'-' 'BEGIN { split("Jan Feb Mar Apr May Jun Jul Aug Sep Oct Nov Dec", month, " "); } { printf "%s-%s-%s\n", $1, month[int($2)], $3; }'
```

**Explanation:**

First, we change awk's field delimiter to the `-` character.  This makes it where the positional variables will now contain day, month, and year.
The `BEGIN` block runs before the first row is processed.  For simplicity's sake, we populate the `month` array by [`split`](http://star-www.rl.ac.uk/docs/sc4.htx/node39.html)-ing a space delimited string.
Then, for each line of input we output a string in the format `%s-%s-%s` where the `%s` will be filled in with the variables we supply.  We have to do this because we've split the input string on `-`, so we need to reassemble it.  The first and third fields are left as-is, but the second field will be cast to a number and used as an index to select the month text.  For example, if `$2` contained `07`, we will cast it to a numerical `7` and use `month[7]` which corresponds to `Jul`.

Comment: Works great, thank you. I'm not too familiar with awk, so I don't have a complete understanding of how this worked, but it did. Now I'll try and break it down on my own.

Comment: @Kit - It's a good time to learn some `awk` then!  I've updated the answer to include a much more detailed explanation.

Answer (score 0):

It would be quite a long, long sed command:

```
 sed -E -e 's/\d\d-01-\d\d\d\d/January/' \
    -e 's/\d\d-02-\d\d\d\d/February/' \
    -e 's/\d\d-03-\d\d\d\d/March/' \
    -e 's/\d\d-04-\d\d\d\d/April/' \
    ...
```

Instead of `sed`, ou can use the `date` command in Unix/Linux. Be careful though. The `date` command works quite differently on BSD platforms like the Mac and GNU platforms like Linux.

On a Mac:

```
$ date -j -f '%d-%m-%Y' '23-01-1994' +"%B"            
January
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you specified `sed`, here is a way to construct the appropriate `sed` command.  First, let's start by defining a `bash` array:

```
months=(01 Jan 02 Feb 03 Mar 04 Apr 05 May 06 Jun 07 Jul 08 Aug 09 Sep 10 Oct 11 Nov 12 Dec)
```

Second, let's create a shell variable `cmd` with all the needed `sed` commands:

```
printf -v cmd 's/[[:digit:]]{2}-%s-[[:digit:]]{4}/%s/g; ' "${months[@]}"
```

Lastly, we use sed:

```
sed -re "$cmd" input_file
```

As an example:

```
$ echo '01-02-2003 01-12-2004' | sed -re "$cmd"
Feb Dec
```

#### More details

With `sed`, 12 substitution commands are needed, one for each month.  The `printf` command creates all 12 from the `months` variable.

```
$ printf -v cmd 's/[[:digit:]]{2}-%s-[[:digit:]]{4}/%s/g; ' "${months[@]}"
$ echo "$cmd"
s/[[:digit:]]{2}-01-[[:digit:]]{4}/Jan/g; s/[[:digit:]]{2}-02-[[:digit:]]{4}/Feb/g; s/[[:digit:]]{2}-03-[[:digit:]]{4}/Mar/g; s/[[:digit:]]{2}-04-[[:digit:]]{4}/Apr/g; s/[[:digit:]]{2}-05-[[:digit:]]{4}/May/g; s/[[:digit:]]{2}-06-[[:digit:]]{4}/Jun/g; s/[[:digit:]]{2}-07-[[:digit:]]{4}/Jul/g; s/[[:digit:]]{2}-08-[[:digit:]]{4}/Aug/g; s/[[:digit:]]{2}-09-[[:digit:]]{4}/Sep/g; s/[[:digit:]]{2}-10-[[:digit:]]{4}/Oct/g; s/[[:digit:]]{2}-11-[[:digit:]]{4}/Nov/g; s/[[:digit:]]{2}-12-[[:digit:]]{4}/Dec/g;
```

The above is lengthy.  Let's just take one substitute command from the list at random:

```
s/[[:digit:]]{2}-09-[[:digit:]]{4}/Sep/g;
```

This looks for any two digits, followed by `-09-` followed by any four digits and replaces that with the string `Sep`.  Because of the final `g`, this is done for every such date found on the line.

Note the use of `[[:digit:]]`.  This will match any digit in whatever locale we are in.  In the modern world with unicode fonts, this is more reliable that the old `[0-9]` form.