# Remove commas and format dates

Tags: awk, sed, grep, tr, nawk

I have a large file with entries such as:

```
<VAL>17,451.26</VAL>
<VAL>353.93</VAL>
<VAL>395.00</VAL>
<VAL>2,405.00</VAL>
<DATE>31 Jul 2013</DATE>
<DATE>31 Jul 2013</DATE>
<DATE>31 Dec 2014</DATE>
<DATE>21 Jun 2002</DATE>
<DATE>10 Jul 2002</DATE>
<MOD>PL</MOD>
<BATCH>13382</BATCH>
<TYPE>Invoice</TYPE>
<REF1>13541/13382</REF1>
<REF2>671042638320</REF2>
<NOTES>a-07 final elec</NOTES>
<SNAME>EDF ENERGY ( Electricity )</SNAME>
<VAL>55.22</VAL>
</CLT>
<CLT>
<CHD>MAT-01</CHD>
<OPN>U5U1</OPN>
<PERIOD>07 2013</PERIOD>
<DATE>13 Jun 2013</DATE>
<DATE>10 Jul 2002</DATE>
<DATE>10 Jul 2002</DATE>
<DATE>21 Aug 2007</DATE>
<DATE>10 Jul 2002</DATE>
<VAL>-4,122,322.03</VAL>
```

I need to remove the commas in the VAL fields and change the dates to YYYY-MM-DD (e.g. 2013-07-31) in the DATE fields.

Looking for a quick (efficient) way of doing this.

Thanks

Comment: `Replace the commas in the VAL fields` with what?

Comment: Sorry, remove, not replace

Comment: Take a look at strtotime() and replace()

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
sed '# init month convertor in holding buffer
1{h;s/.*/Jan01Fev02Mar03Apr04May05Jun06Jul07Aug08Sep09Oct10Nov11Dec12/;x;}

# change Val
  /^<VAL>/ s/,//g

# Change Date
  /^<DATE>/ {
# change month
    G
    s/[[:space:]]\{1,\}\([A-Z][a-z][a-z]\)[[:space:]]\{1,\}\(.*\)\n.*\1\([0-9][0-9]\).*/-\3-\2/
# reformat order
    s/>\(.*\)-\(.*\)-\(.*\)</>\3-\2-\1</
  }' YourFile
```

- posix sed with not extra sub shell for dae conversion
- reformat date take 2 `s///`here but could be merged in 1 `s///` a bit more unreadeable (already very attractive regex like this)
- could easily add some security feature about source date like bad date format

Comment: This has been really useful to me, I've learned a lot. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

This should get you started:

```
awk -F"[<>]" 'BEGIN {split("Jan Feb Mar Apr May Jun Jul Aug Sep Oct Nov Dec",month," ");for (i=1;i<=12;i++) mdigit[month[i]]=i} /<VAL>/ {gsub(/\,/,"")} /<DATE>/  {split($3,a," ");$0=sprintf("<DATE>%s-%02d-%02d</DATE>",a[3],mdigit[a[2]],a[1])}1' file
<VAL>17451.26</VAL>
<VAL>353.93</VAL>
<VAL>395.00</VAL>
<VAL>2405.00</VAL>
<DATE>2013-07-31</DATE>
<DATE>2013-07-31</DATE>
<DATE>2014-12-31</DATE>
<DATE>2002-06-21</DATE>
<DATE>2002-07-10</DATE>
<MOD>PL</MOD>
<BATCH>13382</BATCH>
<TYPE>Invoice</TYPE>
<REF1>13541/13382</REF1>
<REF2>671042638320</REF2>
<NOTES>a-07 final elec</NOTES>
<SNAME>EDF ENERGY ( Electricity )</SNAME>
<VAL>55.22</VAL>
</CLT>
<CLT>
<CHD>MAT-01</CHD>
<OPN>U5U1</OPN>
<PERIOD>07 2013</PERIOD>
<DATE>2013-06-13</DATE>
<DATE>2002-07-10</DATE>
<DATE>2002-07-10</DATE>
<DATE>2007-08-21</DATE>
<DATE>2002-07-10</DATE>
<VAL>-4122322.03</VAL>
```

Comment: Brilliant - I've found this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14342108/converting-months-between-numeric-and-number-using-awk - can you show how the solution could be integrated with yours so that only one pass is required over the file?

Comment: Thanks for you edit - I'm getting `awk: fatal: Unmatched ( or \(: /  {split($3,a," ");$0=sprintf("<DATE>%s-%02d-%s</` with that however @Jotne

Comment: @tozjerimiah Copy past error.  Also added `%0d` to get correct digit in month and day.

Answer (score 1):

Your input seems like XML. I'd use a proper XML handling tool, e.g. [XML::XSH2](http://p3rl.org/XML::XSH2), a wrapper around Perl's [XML::LibXML](http://p3rl.org/XML::LibXML):

```
open file.xml ;
for //VAL set . xsh:subst(., ',', '','g') ;
perl { use Time::Piece } ;
for my $d in //DATE {
    $t = $d/text() ;
    set $d/text() { Time::Piece->strptime($t, '%d %b %Y')->ymd } ;
}
save :b ;
```

Answer (score 1):

This might work for you (GNU sed & bash):

```
sed  -r '/^<VAL>/s/,//g;/^(<DATE>)(.*)(<\/DATE>)$/s//echo "\1"$(date -d "\2" +%F)"\3"/e' file
```

This removes all commas on a line starting `<VAL>` and for those lines that contain date tags, uses the `date` utility and the evaluate flag in the substitution command to rearrange the date to `YYYY-MM-DD`.

An alternative solution, using only seds commands:

```
sed  -r '/^<VAL>/s/,//g;/^<DATE>/!b;s/$/\nJan01Feb02Mar03Apr04May05Jun06Jul07Aug08Sep09Oct10Nov11Dec12/;s/^(<DATE>)(..) (...) (....)(<\/DATE>\n).*\3(..)/\1\4-\6-\2\5/;P;d' file
```

Appends a lookup to the end of the `date` line and uses regexp to rearrange the output.